# PHPMailer and Content-MD5

Tags: php, md5, phpmailer

What is the correct markup for setting a *content-md5* header, especially when using multipart / mime encoded mailings?

`$mail->addCustomHeader('Content-MD5', base64_encode(md5($body)));`

Is it enough to include the body-part of the mail or do I have to include the subject / attachments / ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it won't work that way. Content-MD5 ([RFC1864](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1864.html)) can only be applied to single-item MIME elements such as text/html, and not to a multipart message as a whole. PHPMailer only adds custom headers at the message level (when using `addCustomHeader`), so would not be able to calculate this for an individual part. You'd need to override the `createBody` function to add in that header, and it would be very fiddly.

A better choice overall would be to use DKIM, which gives the same kind of anti-tampering abilities, but it's already there and working and has very wide support from ISPs.

Any particular reason to use Content-MD5 over DKIM?